# Unselect item on pysimplegui listbox re-click

Tags: python, listbox, pysimplegui

I recently started working with pysimplegui on a basic GUI application. My window has a ListBox initialized like this:

```
sg.Listbox(values=[], select_mode="extended", key="list_box", size=(40, 25), enable_events=True)
```

It works great and everything, but after I select an item on the list, I can't unselect it.
I tried to clear the selection like this

```
window["list_box"].update(set_to_index=[])
```

And it works fine, but it feels wrong to me because I would have to keep a state for each `ListBox` about the last item selected to know when a new selection is made or just a re-selection of the previous item.

Bottom line, I want to clear the selection of the `ListBox` when clicking on the same item twice.

Hope I was clear, thanks

Comment: But this would still require me to check on every click and save the last value to only use this method when the same value was selected twice in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/listbox.htm#DEFAULT:~:text=elements%20become%20visible.-,DEFAULT%20BINDINGS,-Tk%20automatically%20creates](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/listbox.htm#DEFAULT:%7E:text=elements%20become%20visible.-,DEFAULT%20BINDINGS,-Tk%20automatically%20creates)

In extended mode, pressing button 1 with the Control key down starts a toggle operation.

Anyway, you can do it like this

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

data = [f'Item {i+1:0>2d}' for i in range(10)]

layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(
        values=data,
        select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_EXTENDED,
        size=(20, 5),
        enable_events=True,
        key="-LISTBOX-",
        metadata=[],
    )],
]
window = sg.Window('Listbox', layout, finalize=True)
listbox = window["-LISTBOX-"]

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)
    if event == "-LISTBOX-":
        metadata = listbox.metadata
        selections = values["-LISTBOX-"]
        print(metadata, selections)
        if metadata == selections:
            listbox.update(set_to_index=[])
            listbox.metadata = []
        else:
            listbox.metadata = values["-LISTBOX-"]

window.close()
```

Note: There's an issue, you cannot click on the same item quickly to select it, or it won't generate any event for the next click(s). It is not an issue of PySimpleGUI or your code, maybe default to `Tk` which automatically creates class bindings for listboxes that give them Motif-like behavior.